# Using Jacobi symbol: Is $(\frac{54}{77})=1$ solvable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I can't understand what to do in the following example of congruence. I need to decide if this congruence is solvable, and if so, to find all the solutions:$x^2 \equiv 54(77)$.

I need to decide whether $(\frac{54}{77})$=1 or -1.

First of all I want to ask you what is the idea behind Jacobi symbol? Do I use it when I need to decide $(\frac{a}{b})$ and $b$ is not a prime?

both of them are not primes, I want to use Jacobi symbol rules:

$(\frac{54}{77})=(\frac{54}{11})(\frac{54}{7})=(\frac{-1}{77})(\frac{5}{77})=(-1)^{-5}(\frac{-2}{7})=1$. But I know that If the reult is 1 then  $54$ may or may not be a quadratic residue $(\mod77)$ . How do I determinate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Jacobi won't work here. Any root $\,x\,$ [persists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/882953/242) $\!\bmod 7\mid 77\,$ 
 but it has no roots $\!\bmod 7\,$ by Euler's Criterion, since
$\!\bmod p\!=\!7\!:\ 54^{(p-1)/2}\equiv (-3^2)^{(p-1)/2)}\equiv -3^{p-1}\equiv -1.\,$ More generally see the Theorem in the dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Deal separately with the solutions of $x^2\equiv 54\pmod{7}$ and $x^2\equiv 54\pmod{11}$, and splice solutions together (if there are any) using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

If there are no solutions mod one of $7$ or $11$, then there are no solutions mod $77$. (Actually, since the Jacobi symbol evaluates to $1$, if there are no solutions mod one of $7$ or $11$, then there are no solutions mod the other.)

**Remark:** You are right, Jacobi symbol evaluating to $1$ is inconclusive. But the Jacobi symbol is cheap to compute, and if it evaluates to $-1$, then end of story. For small numbers, the Jacobi symbol is not as useful, since if we are interested in $x^2\equiv a \pmod{b}$, factorization of $b$ is easy.

Comment: Let's assume that both  $x^2\equiv 54\pmod{7}$ and $x^2\equiv 54\pmod{11}$ are solvable, I know that the Chinese Remainder Theorem is for linear congruences, so how do I use it In this case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, neither is solvable. But pick a number (not $54$) for which both solvable. Typically the solutions are $x\equiv \pm a \pmod{7}$, $x\equiv \pm b\pmod{11}$. Now pick one combination of the solutions, say $x\equiv a\pmod{7}$, $x\equiv -b\pmod{11}$. This is a CRT problem. Solve it. Do same for other $3$ combinations. [In the general case there are $4$ solutions mod $77$, but not, for example, when we use a number like $44$, which is divisible by $11$, basically because $\pm 0=0$.]

Comment: Added to last comment: So to do the calculations, we need to solve the quadratic congruence mod each of $7$ and $11$ first. Then we end up with (typically) $4$ linear congruence problems. Because of $\pm$ symmetry mod $77$, the CRT work need only be done twice.

Comment: Ok, Let's assume the original congruence was $x \equiv 58( mod 77)$. I end up with two solvable congruences: $x^2 \equiv 2(7)$ and $x^2 \equiv 3(11)$. You're telling me that I need to solve the system of $x \equiv 2(7)$ and $x \equiv -3(11)$? I don't understand why.

Comment: That is not what I said. We have $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{7}$. That has the solutions $x\equiv \pm 3\pmod{7}$. The congruence $x^2\equiv 3\pmod{11}$ has the solutions $x\equiv \pm 5\pmod{11}$. Now we need to solve the four systems of congruences (i) $x\equiv 3\pmod{7}$, $x\equiv 5\pmod{11}$; (ii) $x\equiv -3\pmod{7}$, $x\equiv 5\pmod{11}$; (and you know the other two systems). This produces the $4$ solutions mod $77$ of the original congruence.  Please let me know if this is clear!

Comment: It is, Thanks a lot Andre.

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobi symbol is inconclusive here:  $$\big (\frac {54}{77}\big)=\big(\frac {2\cdot 3^3}{7\cdot 11}\big) =\big (\frac 27\big) \big (\frac 3{11}\big)=-\big (\frac 27\big) \big (\frac {-1}3\big) =-(-1)^{\frac {7^2-1}8}\cdot (-1)^{\frac {3-1}2}=-1\cdot (-1)=1.$$

So do $7,11$ separately with the Legendre symbol and apply CRT.  We get $\big (\frac {54}7\big) =\big (\frac {-2}7\big)=(-2)^{\frac{ 7-1}2}\pmod 7=-1. $

So there's no solutions mod $7,$ hence no solutions

Comment: Please don't add answers (to old questions) unless you are sure that it does not duplicate prior content.