# Integer equalities persist as congruences $\!\bmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am told that if $gcd(a,m)=1$ one then there exists integers $x,y$ such that $ax+my=1$ and therefore $ax≡ax+my≡1$ (mod m).

Could someone please explain to me why $ax+my=1$ implies $ax≡ax+my≡1$ (mod m)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equalities in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ always persist as congruences since

$$x = y\,\Rightarrow m\mid x-y\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv y\!\!\!\pmod m$$

[More generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) if $\,m\mid n\,$ then congruences mod $\,n\,$ persist mod $\,m\,$ since

$$ x\equiv y\!\!\!\pmod n,\ \  m\mid n\mid x-y\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid x-y\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv y\!\!\!\pmod m$$

OP is special case $\,n = 0\ $ (by $\,x\equiv y\pmod{\! 0}\!\iff\! 0\mid x-y\iff x=y)$.

Further, by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), roots $\!\bmod n\,$ of a polynomial (with integer coef's) also persist as roots $\!\bmod m\,$ when $\,m\mid n.\,$ In particular $\,(n=0)\,$ integers roots persits as roots $\!\bmod m\,$ for all $\,m$.

Comment: Said *ideally*: if ideals $\,M\supset N$ then there is a natural map $\,R/N\to R/M\,$ via  $\,r+N\mapsto r+M\ \ $