# Does a solution to this congruent equation exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, congruences

Does a solution to this congruent equation exist?
$$\begin{align} 
 &\equiv 14 \pmod {30}\\
 &\equiv 28 \pmod{66}
 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ 14+30j = x = 28+66k\,\Rightarrow\, 14 = 30j-66k = 3(\cdots)\,\Rightarrow\,3\mid 14$

i.e. $\ {\rm mod}\  3\!:\ \color{#c00}{14\equiv x\equiv 28}\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid 28\!-\!14\ $ since [congruences *persist*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1879567/242)  mod factors of the modulus.

---

**Remark** $\ $  Similarly if $\, x\equiv a\pmod m,\ x\equiv b\pmod n\,$ then $\, \color{#c00}{a\equiv x\equiv b}\pmod d\,$ for $\,d =\gcd(m,n),\ $ hence $\,d\mid a-b\ $ is a *necessary* condition for the existence of a solution.

This compatibility condition is also a *sufficient* condition for the existence of solution, and it extends pairwise to any number of congruences - see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857626/242) for a constructive proof (which depends on the key fact that gcd *distributes* over lcm).

Answer (score 0):

$$x\equiv14\pmod{30}\implies x\equiv14\pmod6\equiv2$$

$$x\equiv28\pmod{66}\implies x\equiv28\pmod6\equiv4$$

But $4\not\equiv2\pmod6$

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution.

1)  The two moduli $30, 66$ have greatest common divisor=$6$.

2)  Take the required resudues modulo $6$, that number being the gcd given above.  Thus in the first equation $x\equiv 14 \equiv 2$ mod 6$, in the second equation  $x\eqiiv 28 \equiv 4$ mod 6$.

3)  We can't have any solution congruent with both $2$ and $4$ modulo $6$.  Bummer!