# How do you solve a system of linear congruences with moduli that are not relatively prime to each other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

So I know that if all of your moduli are relatively prime to each other, you can simply apply the Chinese remainder theorem. However, what do you do if the moduli are not relatively prime?

Comment: See [General EASY CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242), or split the congruences into equivalent coprime congruences e.g. as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2294245/242). There are many other threads on this topic which can be located by obvious searches.