# The Modular Part Method (System of congruences)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was reading [this](https://aryansh-s.github.io/The_Art_of_Modular_Arithmetic.pdf) short book about Modular arithmetic, towards the end (Chapter 6.3) it provided a fast way to solve a linear system of congruences, instead of solving two of them at a time. Here's an example of how it works:

$x ≡ 2 (mod 3)≡ 2 (mod 4)≡ 1 (mod 5)$

then it write x as a "sum of three modular parts":

$x ≡ 4 · 5x_3 + 3 · 5x_4 + 3 · 4x_5 $

and it solves each part indipendently:

$x ≡ 4 · 5x_3 ≡ 20x_3 ≡ 2x_3 ≡ 2 (mod 3) ⇒ x_3 ≡ 1 (mod 3)$

$x ≡ 3 · 5x_4 ≡ 15x_4 ≡ −x_4 ≡ 2 (mod 4) ⇒ x_4 ≡ −2 ≡ 2 (mod 4)$

$x ≡ 3 · 4x_5 ≡ 12x_5 ≡ 2x_5 ≡ 1 ≡ 6 (mod 5) ⇒ x_5 ≡ 3 (mod 5)$

and at the end it substitute the values that it found:
$x ≡ 4 · 5 · 1 + 3 · 5 · 2 + 3 · 4 · 3 ≡ 86 ≡ 26 (mod 60)$

I don't understand why this is true and when this is true, I have tried with a few systems and when the gcd of the modulus isn't 1 it doesn't work. (the explanation on the book is: The reason these coefficients ensure independence is that if we look at x in a given modulus, the irrelevant parts disappear. For instance, (mod 4) or (mod 5), the (mod 3) part 4 · 5x3 disappears, but (mod 3), 4 · 5x3 is all that remains)
Online I haven't found this method, does it have another name? Is there a place that explains this way of solving system of congruences and gives a proof of why it works?

Comment: This is the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: This is in the typical proof of the "Chinese Remainder Theorem". It's the same idea as in Lagrange Interpolation for polynomials.

Comment: The explanation that the parts disapear seems pretty straight forward as $4\cdot 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{4,5}$ and $2\cdot 3\equiv 0 \pmod{2,3}$ etc.  As for being relatively prime must divide all terms by the gcd and it should work.

Comment: This is the idea in the proof of CRT and the method to solve for $x \equiv a_i \pmod{m_i}$. The author mentions this before.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) in the linked dupe for a detailed explanation for why this common CRT formula works.

Comment: @BillDubuque sorry I can't comment on that post.
I still don't understand why this works, why can we write it as a sums, an multiply each term by some number. I understand why there exist a solution modulo the lcm of all numbers but not why this method finds it.
Can i understand it without knowledge of abstract algebra?

Comment: The first few paragraphs of the answer linked in my prior comment explains why the CRT formula yields a solution of the congruence system. Precisely which part of that don't you understand? That formula only works when the moduli are pairwise coprime.

Comment: See the answers linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4881571/242) for methods for solving congruence systems whose moduli are not pairise coprime.

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm sorry, the only part that I understood is that $-5*7 = 1 (mod 3)$, $3*7 = 1 (mod 5)$ and $ 7*3 = 1 (mod 7)$ I don't understand why you have summed "them". It is clear that when we reduce the formula mod (3, 5 or 7) only one part remain, but I don't understand what is the meaning of this and why does multiplying by the $lcm/m_i$  yields a correct answer.

Comment: They must be summed because each summand yields the sought value for only one modulus (the summand is $\equiv 0$ mod all other moduli). What is not clear in the explanation there, viz: "when reduced $\!\bmod  \color{#c00}3,\,$ the 2nd and 3rd summands are $\equiv\color{#c00} 0,\,$ both having factors of $\,\color{#c00}3,\,$ so the formula reduces to  $\, x\equiv a\color{#0a0}{(1)} \color{#c00}{+ 0 + 0}\equiv a,\,$ as sought.  Similarly $\!\bmod 5\,$ and $\!\bmod 7.$" That proves that the integer given by the formula  is a solution of all $3$ congruences in the system.

Comment: @BillDubuque really thank you, I now understand why this works. You helped me a lot!