# Is Chinese Remainder Theorem a double implication?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I mean, if you have multiples equations and all modulus are co-primes you can 'merge' them in just one equation.

But can you do it reversed? Something like:

(a mod p*q)   p and q co-prime

And then create the equations (a mod p) and (a mod q). 
I've seen that:

18≡18(mod 35) but

18≡4(mod 7) and 18≡3(mod 5)

But I've seen other questions where it was told that you are able to do it.

Comment: Yes.  The Chinese remainder theorem establishes a bijection between residue classes $\pmod {pq}$ which are prime to $pq$, and pairs of classes $\pmod p, \pmod q$ both prime to their respective modulus.

Comment: Ok, but what about the example i proposed?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  $18$ is a good residue class $\pmod {5\times 7}$.  We check that $\gcd(18,5\times 7)=1$, so that checks.  So the CRT should give us a pair of residue classes $a\pmod 5$ and $b\mod 7$ which corresponds to it.  We confirm that $(a,b)=(3,4)$ so we're good.  What's the problem?

Comment: Combinatorially, this means that the number of classes $\pmod {35}$ which are prime to $35$ should be the product of the number of classes $\pmod 5$ and $\pmod 7$ which are prime to their respective modulus.  If you know about the [Euler phi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), this just means that $\varphi(35)=\varphi(5)\times \varphi(7)$.  Since the numbers are all so small you can check this by hand.

Comment: So it doesnt matter if the residues are not the same in the new both equations? I've seen that CRT had two equations with an x that should be the same

Comment: What does "the same" mean?  A class $\pmod 5$ is never going to be a class $\pmod 7$.  They intersect, of course.  At $18$.  But they are not "the same".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This direction of the statement is trivially true.

If $x \equiv a \pmod  {pq}$, then $pq \mid (x-a)$.

So $p \mid (x-a) $ and $q \mid (x-a)$.

So, $x \equiv a \pmod p$ and $x \equiv a \pmod q$.

Comment: i.e. [congruences persist mod factors of the modulus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242)

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment)

I think your original doubt came from a common misunderstanding about notation. $$x \equiv a \pmod  {n}$$ does not mean that $x$, reduced modulo $n$, equals $a$. It means that the difference between $a$ and $x$ is a multiple of $n$, or, to look at it another way, that $a$ reduced modulo $n$ and $x$ reduced modulo $n$ are equal.

It is true that $13 \equiv -478847 \pmod  {10}$, for example.