# How to solve linear congruence with an unknown variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

For example: Solve for $a$ given the following linear congruence.

> $$ \begin{align}x &≡ a \mod 7 \\x &≡ 3 \mod 35\end{align}$$

So far I tried solving the question using the Chinese remainder theorem mainly by solving "backwards" but I just can't seem to make it work

Comment: Write down what both of these lines mean (start with the second one) and it should appear instantly. There is no need for a theorem.

Comment: the Chinese remainder theorem is for two relatively prime moduli

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, sure but it generalizes to a lcm form.

Answer (score 1):

$\ \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\begin{align}\bmod 5(\color{#c00}7)\!:\ &3\equiv x\\ \color{#0a0}\Longrightarrow\ \bmod\ \ \   \color{#c00}7\!:\ \ \ &3\equiv x\equiv a\iff  a = 3+7n\ \ \text{for some integer $n$}\end{align}$

by congruences $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{persist}\,$ mod $\rm\color{#c00}{factors}$ of the modulus, by [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) This *fundamental*  property of congruences should be known like the back of your hand  to be proficient with congruences.

Answer (score 0):

translate the modular statements to divisibility statements:

if $7\times5=35|x-3$ then certainly $7|x-3$, so $a=3$

Answer (score 0):

Given $$x\equiv a \mod 7 \implies x = 7k +a \quad \text{ (1.)}$$

Also $$x \equiv 3 \mod 35 \implies x = 35l + 3 \quad \text { (2.)}$$

multiplying $(1.)$ by $5$ and subtracting $(2.)$ from it ,

$$5x  -x = 35(k-l) + (5a-3) \\ \color{#0c9}{4x \equiv \,(5a-3) \mod 35}$$

But from $(2.)$ , we also get $\,\,\,4x \equiv 12 \mod 35 $.

By comparing the equations , we get

$$5a-3 = 12 \implies \boxed{\color{#2ca}{a = 3}}$$