# Trial Division and Quadratic Reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, factoring, quadratic-reciprocity

I am reading *The Joy of Factoring* by Samuel Wagstaff and I am having trouble understanding a paragraph from this book. It says the following

> One can use quadratic residues to speed Trial Division by skipping
>   some primes that cannot be divisors. This device was used by Euler,
>   Gauss, and others hundreds of years ago. Let N be the number to
>   factor. Suppose we know a nonsquare quadratic residue r modulo N.
>   Then r is also a quadratic residue modulo any prime factor p of N.
>   If r is not a square, the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity restricts p to
>   only half of the possible residue classes modulo 4|r|.

There are two things which I am not sure I understand correctly:

-When it says that a nonsquare quadratic residue mod $N$ is also a quadratic residue mod any prime factor $p$ of $N$. (I think this is because of the Chinese Remainder Theorem but I am not sure)

-When it says that if $r$ is not a square, the law of quadratic reciprocity restricts $p$ to only half of the possible residue classes modulo $4|r|$. I know that for example if $r$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ then $p$ must also be a quadratic residue mod $m$ by the law of quadratic reciprocity, however this would restrict the possible values of $p$ to half of the residue classes mod $r$ not mod $4|r|$.

I am confused

Answer (score 0):

> When it says that a nonsquare quadratic residue mod N is also a quadratic residue mod any prime factor p of N. (I think this is because of the Chinese Remainder Theorem but I am not sure)

$\ r\equiv a^2\pmod{\!N\!=\!\color{#c00}pk}\,\Rightarrow\, r\equiv a^2\pmod{\!\color{#c00}p}\,$ by [congruences persist mod $\rm\color{#c00}{factors}$ of the modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242)

> When it says that if r is not a square, the law of quadratic reciprocity restricts p to only half of the possible residue classes modulo 4|r|. I know that for example if r is a quadratic residue mod p then p must also be a quadratic residue mod m by the law of quadratic reciprocity, however this would restrict the possible values of p to half of the residue classes mod r not mod 4|r|.

Consider first the case $\,r = q\,$ prime. By quadratic reciprocity

$$\chi(p) := (q|p) = (p|q)^{\large \frac{p-1}2 \frac{q-1}2}$$

so $\,\chi(p+\color{#c00}4q) = \chi(p)$ since adding $4q$ to $p$ preserves the parity of $(p-1)/2$ so doesn't affect the sign factor, and preserves $(p/q)$ by $\,p+4q\equiv p\pmod{\!q}.\,$ Generally $4q$ is the least such value, e.g.

$$\begin{align} (3|p) = 1 &\iff p\equiv -1,1\ \ \ \pmod {\color{#c00}4\cdot 3}\\[.2em]
(-5|p) \equiv 1 &\iff p\equiv 1,3,7,9\!\!\pmod{\color{#c00}4\cdot 5}\end{align}$$

When $r$ is a product of odd primes $q_i$ this extends by multiplicativity to the lcm of $\,4q_i$ which is $ 4\prod q_i = 4r.\,$ For a rigorous proof see e.g. section $2.5$ (Quadratic Residue Characters) in Harvey Cohn's book *Advanced Number Theory*. It derives this  *resolution modulus* for the Jacobi symbol.

Comment: Perhaps my issue is when they say that it restricts the possible values of $p$ to -only- half of the possible classes mod $4|r|$. In your example $p$ is reduced to only two possible values mod 12 not half of the residue classes mod 12. I still don't understand why if 3 is a quadratic residue then $p \equiv -1,1$ (mod 12)?

Comment: @ElPerro For $(3|p)$ our $p$ is odd and coprime to $3$ so coprime to $12$ so there are $\phi(12) = 4$ possibilities, which halved $= 2\,\color{#c00}\checkmark\,$ For $(-5|p)$ our $p$ is odd and coprime to $5$ so coprime to $20$ so there are $\phi(20) = 8$ possibilities, which halved $= 4\,\color{#c00}\checkmark$