# Prove a modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a\equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $d\mid n$, then  $a\equiv1 \pmod d$ is true.

That is the question I am trying to understand so I have some understanding of the question but cant place my finger on exactly why it is true.

$n = d \times k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$a = k \times n +1$ and $a= k \times d +1$

$n \mid(a-1)$ and $d \mid(a-1)$

Comment: If $(a-1)=m\times n$ and $n=d\times k$ then $(a-1)=d\times (m\times k)$.

Comment: Use `\pmod`, not `\mod`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that one.

Comment: @lulu where does the $m$ come from ?

Comment: You said that $(a-1)\equiv 0 \pmod n$.  that means $n\,|\,(a-1)$.  Thus there is some integer $m$ such that $(a-1)=m\times n$.

Comment: $a\equiv1\pmod n\iff a=1+nN$ so if $n=dm$ you have $a=1+dmN\Rightarrow a\equiv1\pmod d$

Comment: Yes, [congruences persist mod divisors of the modulus,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) as proved in the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ is congruent to 1 modulo $n$, then $a$ is one more than a multiple of $n$.

If $d$ divides $n$, then $n$ is a multiple of $d$. Hence, $a$ is also one more than a multiple of $d$. So we say $a$ is congruent to 1 module $d$.

Comment: can this be shown with an equation like what @lulu pointed out?

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.